# Z-fighting. Inaccurate coordinates of faces / shakes

Tags: three.js, webgl, zbuffer

For sufficiently large approaching the surface of the sphere, which is a model of the Earth, I get inaccurate coordinates of vertices. Because of this, when moving the camera the shaking noticeable.

How to get rid of it? On the Internet to find solutions to invert zNear and zFar, but I have no idea how to do it in three.js

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ugly render on clouds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747759/ugly-render-on-clouds)

Comment: @LJ_1102, No, definitely I have another problem. I do not have "overlapping" of polygons as in the following example http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_camera_logarithmicdepthbuffer When nearest the camera position to the vertices obtained as though inaccurate coordinates of the vertices

Answer (score 0):

THREE.PerspectiveCamera has near and far parameters. These define the distance of the near and far clipping plane.

You have to choose clipping planes depending on your scene. For example if you have a large scene, and the near plane is very small, it can cause things you experienced.

Comment: Of course I have set values for the near = 0.01, far = 10000.
Value of the variable near I can not put anymore since then I can not watch nearby objects

Comment: Then maybe you can try to set far to a smaller value if it is possible.

Comment: it also can not change

Comment: Then I think that the only solution is to always change clipping planes during navigation.

Comment: How to do it in three.js?

Comment: I think you can just set the PerspectiveCamera's near and far property. Maybe you need to call updateProjectionMatrix after the modification.

Comment: Decrease far does not give any result, for example, if the near = 0.01 and far = 0.1, it is still get a "shake" coordinates.
This is likely to depend on large coordinate values administers. But how can this be avoided?